# How can I validate a Gaussian Mixture Model?

Tags: normal-distribution, model, validation, mixture-distribution

I am currently working with a dataset composed by 14 continuous variables and 100 observations. My goal is to select variables of interest to build consistent clusters and doing classification. I was thinking about using Gaussian Mixture Model.

Indeed, to select variables and to find the best model, I used the "vscc" package in R. After that, I can fit my model with the selected variables to find clusters. By the way, I used K-means clustering to improve prior information for the EM algorithm.

My question is simple, are there any assumptions that we have to validate concerning the variables (should the variables follow a normal distribution?).
Moreover, how can I validate my model, firstly, looking at the BIC to select the number of components and then looking at the variance covariance matrix in each component is a reasonable solution?

Comment: I guess the components of your mixture should follow normal distribution, the variables will not follow normal distribution in the case of mixture.